# Powershell match similar entries in an array

Tags: powershell, powercli

I've written myself a script to check for vm-folders in vmware vcenter that dont match the corresponding vmname.
There are a few automatically deployed VMs which i need to exclude from this check. Those VMs are always similarly named, but with an incremented number at the end. I've declared an array $Vmstoginrore containing strings of them and i'm trying to match my $VmName with this array but it does not work. Ive also tried it with like but i cannot seem to get this to work.

```
$Vmstoignore=@( "Guest Introspection","Trend Micro Deep Security")
$VmName = "Guest Introspection (4)"

    if ($Vmstoignore-match $VmName ){
        Write-Output "does match"
    }
    else {
        Write-Output "doesn't match"
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- As of v7.2.x, **PowerShell offers *no* [comparison operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators) that accept an *array* of comparison values** (only the *input* operand - the LHS - is allowed to be an array).
- However, sine the **[`-match` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match-and--notmatch)** is [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions)-based, you can **use a single regex with an alternation (`|`) to match *multiple* patterns**.

  - Note that the regex pattern to match against must be the *RHS* (right-hand side) operand of `-match` (e.g. `'foo' -match '^f'` - in your question, the operands are mistakenly reversed).

The following code shows how to **construct the regex *programmatically*** from the given, literal array elements (VM name prefixes):

```bash
# VM name prefixes to match.
$Vmstoignore = @("Guest Introspection", "Trend Micro Deep Security")

# Construct a regex with alternation (|) from the array, requiring
# the elements to match at the *start* (^) of the input string.
# The resulting regex is:
#    ^Guest\ Introspection|^Trend\ Micro\ Deep\ Security
$regex = $Vmstoignore.ForEach({ '^' + [regex]::Escape($_) }) -join '|'

# Sample input name.
$VmName = "Guest Introspection (4)"

# Now match the input name against the regex:
# -> $true
$VmName -match $regex
```

Note:

- You may **alternatively construct the regex *directly* as a string**, in which case you need to *manually* `\`-escape any regex metacharacters, such as `.` (no escaping is required with your sample array):

  ```bash
  $regex = '^Guest Introspection|^Trend Micro Deep Security'
  ```
- Note that [`[regex]::Escape()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Escape) escapes   (spaces) as `\` , even though spaces aren't metacharacters. However, if the `x` (`IgnorePatternWhiteSpace`) [regex option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-options) is in effect (e.g. by placing `(?x)` at the start of the regex), spaces that are a meaningful part of the pattern *do* require this escaping. In the absence of this option (it is *off* by default), escaping spaces is *not* necessary.
- For a detailed explanation of the regex and the ability to interact with it, see [this regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/sqIyvk/1).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and the detailed explenation. It's working now.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @HannesW.; my pleasure.